# lc.exe has problems running from a service (CC.NET) in Vista x64

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, 64-bit

When running CC.NET as a service I get the following error:

LC0004: Exception occurred creating type 'C1.Win.C1Command.C1CommandHolder, C1.Win.C1Command, Version=1.0.20044.97, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e808566f358766d8' System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'C1.Win.C1Command.12' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid. in licenses.licx(7, 0)

I do not get this error if I run CC.NET from the console nor when I directly run the msbuild script.  I did not get this under XP as a service.  I've found other places where people have reported similar errors (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/f8f4590f-cf5e-4593-8848-960fa460aa07) but nothing with a real solution.

Comment: This sounds like a bug.  Have you posted something on their support forum? http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNETCOMM/Community

Answer (score 1):

this issue will be fixed in the next build of C1Command.

-AlexeyS, C1